# Запрет на многократный вызов события при действиях с мышью

Tags: c#, события, логика, xna

Всем доброго времени суток!

Пишу собственный GUI-интерфейс для игрушки.

Класс `Button`.

Имеется следующий набор событий-делегатов:

```
public event EventHandler MouseUpHandler;
public event EventHandler MouseDownHandler;
public event EventHandler MouseOutHandler;
public event EventHandler MouseInHandler;
```

Каждому из событию соответствует свой метод:

```
private void OnMouseIn() {...}
private void OnMouseOut() {...}
private void OnMouseUp() {...}
private void OnMouseDown() {...}
```

В них выполняется примерно такой код:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    EventHandler tempHandler = MouseDownHandler; // получаем делегат события
    if (tempHandler != null) // проверяем, не пустой ли делегат
    {
        tempHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty); // вызываем событие
    }
    _state = ButtonState.Click; // используется для определения правильных координат на спрайте текстуры кнопки во время ее рисования
}
```

Соответствующие методы присутствуют для других событий-делегатов.
В этом же классе присутствует метод 
`Update()`, который просчитывает логику кода:

```
public void Update()
{
     /* Формируем данные о положении мыши и о зоне пересечения (на основе позиции и размеров кнопки) */
     MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
     Point mousePosition = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y); 

     Rectangle buttonRectangle = new Rectangle
     (
        (int) this.Position.X, (int) this.Position.Y,
        (int) this.Size.X, (int) this.Size.Y
     );

     if (buttonRectangle.Contains(mousePosition)) // проверяем на наличие пересечения курсора мыши и кнопки
     {
         if (mouseState.LeftButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed) //ЛКМ - нажатие кнопки мыши
         {
             OnMouseDown();
         }
         if (_mousePrevState.LeftButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed 
         && mouseState.LeftButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Released) // ЛКМ - отпускание кнопки мыши
         {
             OnMouseUp();
         }
     } else // выход курсора за границы кнопки
     {
         OnMouseOut();
     }
    _mousePrevState = mouseState; // сохраняем предыдущее состояние (MouseUp может быть только после MouseDown)
}
```

В другом месте создается экземпляр кнопки:

```
Button button = new Button(...);
```

Соответственно задаются свойства, текстуры и т.д. Все это функционирует. 
Далее, в том же "другом месте", делегату присваивается метод:

```
button.MouseInHandler += Название_метода;
```

С этим, думаю, все должно быть понятно. 
Логика вкратце - создается объект, ему в специальный делегат присваивается метод, после чего в методе 
`Update()` проверяется, было ли пересечение кнопки и курсора, был ли клик и т.д. и на основе этого уже вызывается нужное нам событие.

**Проблема, которая имеется сейчас:** метод вызывается не единожды, а множество раз подряд.

Все это приводит к тому, что, например, вывод в консоль любого текста происходит множество раз, но требуется не более одного.

Я попробовал решить проблему с помощью дополнительных полей:

```
private bool _isMouseUp;
private bool _isMouseDown;
private bool _isMouseIn;
private bool _isMouseOut;
```

С изменением структуры логики методов-событий:

```
private void OnMouseIn()
{
    if (!_isMouseIn) // если событие не вызывалось 
    {
         EventHandler tempHandler = MouseInHandler;
         if (tempHandler != null)
         {
              tempHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
         _isMouseIn = true; // определяем событие, как вызванное и не даем ему совершиться повторно
         _isMouseOut = false; // после In события можно допустить выполнение Out события
    }
    _state = ButtonState.Hover;
}
// примерно такой же код ниже, разве что теперь Out и In поменялись местами
private void OnMouseOut()
{
    if (!_isMouseOut)
    {
         EventHandler tempHandler = MouseOutHandler;
         if (tempHandler != null)
         {
              tempHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
         _isMouseOut = true;
         _isMouseIn = false;
    }
    _state = ButtonState.Normal;
}
```

Для `MouseDown` и `MouseUp` соответствующие изменения.

И все это работает, до тех пор, пока пользователь ведет себя нормально. Однако если пробовать различные ситуации, например, зажать ЛКМ, после чего навести на кнопку и отпустить, или зажать ЛКМ над кнопкой и отпустить ее в другом месте - все это приводит к тому, что в какой-либо момент то или иное событие, которое должно было быть вызвано - не вызывается, либо наоборот, вызывается то событие, которые вызываться не должно.

Я попробовал как можно более подробно описать свою проблему, но если будут какие-нибудь вопросы - задавайте, уточню, если нужно.

Comment: А вы пробовали отслеживать последовательность возникновения событий и их обработку с помощью `Debug.WriteLine("Было событие нажатия на лев.клавишу")` и т.д.? Похоже, что где-то нужна наряду с подпиской на событие отписка от него, хотя я не уверен.

Comment: Да. Я определил методы с таким содержанием: http://pastebin.com/CUvpEdNZ
Собственно, это и позволило мне понять, что события вызываются многократно. 
Про поводу отписки и подписки - это логично, я пытался сделать это с помощью доп. полей, но чую, что подход немного не верный, так как начинается переплетение из = true, = false и в определенный момент код становится невозможно читать.

Comment: Еще разик перечитал предпоследний абзац и появилась вот какая мысль: вот в WPF есть tunneling & bubbling событий, только там события `RoutedEvent` и там можно в обработчике событий командой `e.Handled` остановить дальнейший нисходящий или восходящий вызов событий. Похоже, что вам нужно реализовывать нечто подобное.

Comment: @Bulson +1, или как в формах, вызывать событие только для верхнего видимого элемента, и игнорировать для нижних. А еще неплохо бы избавиться от необходимости проверять событие на null, и защититься от пропихивания туда этого самого null. Объявление событий чуть потолстеет, зато обработчики похудеют, что к лучшему, ибо они выполняются, в отличие от объявлений.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Обычно для UI-элементов вводят понятие Capture.

Когда происходит событие `MouseDown`, текущий элемент под мышью фиксируется. Эта фиксация и называется capture. После этого все события о перемещении мыши доставляются **только этому элементу**. При этом событие отпускания мыши тянет за собой автогенерацию клика только если при этом мышь была внутри элемента с capture. После отпускания мыши capture обнуляется.

Таким образом исчезают неожиданные комбинации событий. Вы можете проверить работу capture на окне какого-нибудь приложения: нажмите на крестик закрытия окна в правом верхнем углу, и, не отпуская кнопку мыши, уведите её из кнопки. Теперь отпустите мышь, крестик не сработает.

---

Кстати, у вас в коде логическая ошибка: для MouseDown нужно проверять предыдущее состояние точно так же, как вы делаете для MouseUp: MouseDown происходит только если предыдущее состоянии мыши было ненажатым.

Comment: Благоденствую. 
Используя правки, внесенные Вами в логическую структуру кода и добавив отслеживание Capture у элемента, я достиг желаемого и получил вполне приемлемый код.